# Question about an ODE Theorem from Marsden and Hoffman

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

So theorem $5.7.2$ states:

Under the above assumptions (the assumptions are a contraction mapping I believe), there is a $\delta>0$ such that the equation:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(t,x),\space x(t_0)=x_0$$

Has a unique $C^1$ solution with $x(t)=\phi(t)$, with $\phi(t_0)=x_0$ for $t_0-\delta<t_0<t_0+\delta$, i.e $\phi'(t)=f(t,\phi(t))$.

This theorem on it's surface make sense to me, but then I'm given the following problem:

Consider $\frac{dx}{dt}=x^2$ with $x(0)=1.$  Solve this explicitly to see that $\delta$ is finite.

This differential equation is easy to solve either by separating the differential equation or proceeding via Picard Iteration, but what is $\delta$? Is it not $0$? since $\phi(0)=1$ for only $t=0$? And now I'm not really sure what this theorem is saying, should $\delta$ always be zero when you solve the differential equation?

Comment: $\delta$ is the radius of the neighborhood of the initial time in which the solution you've found holds.

Comment: **HINT**: At what time $t$ does your explicit solution to the ODE with $x(0)=1$ blow up?

Comment: @TedShifrin at $t=1$ I believe. Oh wait, is the $t_0-\delta<t<t_0+\delta$ referring to the whole solution and not just the $\phi(t_0)=x_0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict the consideration to some neighborhood of the initial point, $x\in[0,2]$. Then $M=\max_{x\in[0,2]}|x^2|=4$. Solution can not grow faster than with slope $4$ in that set, so restrict the time to the interval $|t|\leδ=\frac14$. The Lipschitz constant of $x^2$ on $[0,2]$ is likewise $L=\max_{x\in[0,2]}|2x|=4$. As $Lδ=1$, you get a contraction constant $q=Lδ'<1$ for any $δ'<δ$, so that a solution can be extended to at least the interval $[-\frac14,\frac14]$.